# Wireless Mouse Setup

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-mouse

I have an Asus netbook running Ubuntu.  I have a wireless Kensington mouse also,  when I insert the USB,  it is not picking up and my ports are working fine.  Could it be that the mouse only work with Windows?

Comment: What is the exact mouse model? Does Kensington report it's compatible with Linux OSs?  Have you ensured the mouse actually works (on a Windows machine)?

Comment: Looks like that the drivers of the Kensington Mouse aren't compatible with Linux (Ubuntu). By the way did you have installed the drivers for the mouse on Ubuntu?

Comment: Whats the computer model?

Comment: Kensington Si750m Le Wireless Notebook Laser Mouse

Comment: Yes it works on windowd

Comment: I don't see any drivers for touchpad installed and I don't know how to do it without a mouse.

Comment: I mean how am I going to connect to Wi-Fi?  Without mouse to enable and stuff

Comment: A USB mouse should just work, if it is not working, then there is something else going on.  This answer does not explain how to get the mouse working, I seriously doubt, that it is impossible to use a wireless USB mouse just because its a specific Kensington mouse.  *Even then you can use the built-in trackpad or a different mouse if you had to*

Comment: When I insert the receiver found in the back of the mouse into my netbook and do an "xinput" command in terminal,  it shows it..

Comment: You should `edit` new info (model #, xinput tests/results, etc.) into your actual question.

Comment: Happy New Year guys,  and thanks for your assistance yesterday.  The mouse is working,  it didn't require any special driver to run on Linux.